# update / regenerate pom.xml in Roo

Tags: spring-roo, pom.xml

I've got a project that was made with Spring Roo 1.0 that I now want to continue using Spring Roo 1.1.4 with. A lot has changed since then, so I would like Roo to update the pom.xml as I seem to remember it used to do that. However, it doesn't touch my pom.xml at all. What can I do to force it to update the pom.xml (at the very least change the dependency on Roo 1.0.0 to 1.1.4 :-) )

Cheers

Comment: If you open the Roo shell in your project directory with the new Roo, nothing happens? Have you done many manual changes in the generated files?

Comment: Not really. I have made changes in the pom.xml, added dependencies mainly. If I remove all the .aj files and launch roo, they regenerate just fine. But if I remove all roo/spring/jpa dependencies from the pom.xml and launch roo, nothing happens. If I leave my pom as it is and launch roo, it doesn't update it to 1.1.4 either

Comment: Start a new project, run the log.roo script with the new version and add your changes to pom after?

Comment: Being the first Roo project we ever did, we didn't think of committing the log, so it's unfortunately been gone for a year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the `log.roo` file than you should go through to 'official' upgrade process described in the [Roo docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/upgrade.html#upgrade-any):

> - Run the backup command using your currently-installed (i.e. existing)
>     version of Spring Roo. This will help
>     create a ZIP of your project, which
>     may help if you need to revert. Don't
>     install the new version of Roo until
>     you've firstly completed this backup.
>     Naturally you can skip this step if
>     you have an alternate backup technique
>     and have confidence in it.
> - Edit your project's pom.xml and verify the Spring Roo annotations JAR
>     matches the new Roo release you are
>     installing. Spring Roo 1.1.0.M3 and
>     above will do this automatically on
>     your behalf when you load it on an
>     existing project.
> - Edit your project's pom.xml and verify that major libraries match the
>     new versions that are now used by Roo.
>     The simplest approach to doing this is
>     to create a new directory and use "roo
>     script clinic.roo" and then diff your
>     existing pom.xml against the
>     newly-created Petclinic pom.xml.
> - After modifying the pom.xml as described above, you will need to
>     update your Eclipse .classpath file.
>     The simplest way to achieve this is to
>     use mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
>     from the command prompt, or use the
>     perform eclipse command at the roo>
>     shell prompt. You can skip this step
>     if you use m2eclipse, as would be the
>     case for any SpringSource Tool Suite
>     user.

Comment: Thanks, my bad for trying to do this without checking the docs